# Bubble Sort in Linked List in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote that code on x86. My strings are:
 
`'Pistachios : A native of Syria'`
`'Hazels : A native of Europe and south west Asia'`
`'Almonds : A native of the eastern Mediterranean region'`

However,when i wanted to print the new sorted list,
i get only `'Almonds : A native of the eastern Mediterranean region'` as output.
Thank you for helping me

```
 STACK_SEG SEGMENT STACK USE16

 DB 100 DUP(?)
STACK_SEG ENDS     


DATA_SEG SEGMENT 'DATA' USE16

LIST_ORG DW PIS
PIS DW HAZ
DB 'Pistachios : A native of Syria$'
HAZ DW ALM
DB 'Hazels : A native of Europe and south west Asia$'
ALM DW 0
DB 'Almonds : A native of the eastern Mediterranean region$'
NEWLINE DB 0DH,0AH,'$'
DATA_SEG ENDS 




CODE_SEG SEGMENT PARA 'CODE' PUBLIC USE16
ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG, DS:DATA_SEG, SS:STACK_SEG
MAIN PROC FAR
PUSH DS ;INITIATE THE PROGRAM
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA_SEG
MOV DS,AX   


MOV DI,LIST_ORG  
MOV CX,3
MOV BX,5
LOOP1:
CMP BX,0H
JE EXIT
MOV BX,0H   
LOOP2:
  CMP CX,1
  JE DONE2
  MOV SI,[DI] 


  MOV AL,[DI+2]
  MOV AH,[SI+2]

  CMP AH,AL
  JL CHANGE
  DEC CX
  JMP LOOP2
  CHANGE:  
  XCHG SI,DI
  DEC CX
  INC BX
  JMP LOOP2

  DONE2:
  JMP LOOP1
  EXIT:


  AGAIN2:
  MOV AH,9
  LEA DX,DI+2;first 2 byte is pointer
  INT 21H 

  MOV AH,9
  LEA DX,NEWLINE
  INT 21H 


   MOV SI,[DI]
   CMP SI,0
   JZ RETT
   MOV DI,SI
   JMP AGAIN2
  RETT:

   RET
MAIN ENDP
CODE_SEG ENDS              
END MAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MOV DX, NEWLINE
```

instead of

```
LEA DX, NEWLINE
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but i got 'Wrong Parameters' error when i tried this.